# Databind LiveData to CustomView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I have a ViewModel with a List auf `MutableLiveData<Data>` in my Fragment Layout I set the data variable of my CustomView with one of the data elements from the List.

This works fine when it first loads but it doesn't update when I change a value in my data object.

Not really sure how to do this, until now I just used two-way data binding with EditText and MutableLiveData for example.

CustomView Layout:

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="data"
        type="androidx.lifecycle.LiveData<Data>"/>
</data>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@{data.color}"
            app:cardCornerRadius="16dp">
```

Class:

```
var data: MutableLiveData<Data>? = null
    set(value) {
        binding.data = value
    }
```

Fragment Layout:

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type=".ViewModel" />
</data>

<CustomView
        .
        .
        .
        app:data="@{viewModel.data[1]}" />
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason for the update only happening the first time the screen is loaded is that the XML is used to inflate the View and then the initial item is used and set to the CustomView.
Then when the item in the list is updated, it does not trigger an update in the CustomView.

What you might be looking for is `@BindingAdapter`

```
@BindingAdapter("enableButton")
internal fun Button.enableButton(enabled: Boolean?) = enabled?.let { isEnabled = it } ?: also { isEnabled = false }
```

And then using it in the following way:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button Text"
    app:enableButton="@{viewModel.observeStatus()}" /> // <- Observes Boolean
```

A good walk-through might be at the following link: [BindingAdapter](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters)

Note: The example is only for a Boolean observation, but it can simply be changed to match whatever object is observed.